type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'PigeonUserDetails?' in type cast
I am trying to log in using firebase using the Google Login in and trying to register a username and account. Basically any authentication process i try to do i get the following error:
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'PigeonUserDetails?' in type cast
Here is the code for my google login in and registering using username and password:
class LoginAccountBloc extends Bloc<LoginAccountEvent, LoginAccountState> {
  LoginAccountBloc() : super(LoginAccountInitial()) {
    on<LoginAccountSubmitted>(
      (event, emit) async {
        emit(LoginAccountSubmitting());
        try {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: event.email,
            password: event.password,
          );
          emit(LoginAccountSuccessful());
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
            emit(LoginAccountFailure('No user found for that email.'));
          } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
            emit(LoginAccountFailure('Wrong password provided for that user.'));
          } else {
            emit(LoginAccountFailure(e.toString()));
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}



class RegisterAccountBloc
    extends Bloc<RegisterAccountEvent, RegisterAccountState> {
  RegisterAccountBloc() : super(RegisterAccountInitial()) {
    on<RegisterAccountSubmitted>(
      (event, emit) async {
        print(event.username);
        print(event.email);
        print(event.password);
        emit(RegisterAccountSubmitting());
        if (event.username.isEmpty ||
            event.email.isEmpty ||
            event.password.isEmpty) {
          emit(RegisterAccountFailure("All fields are required."));
          return;
        }
        print('All fields are written');
        try {
          // Step 1: Create a new user with Firebase Authentication

          final credential =
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: event.email,
            password: event.password,
          );
          print('Added Credentials to FirebaseAuth');
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
            emit(RegisterAccountFailure('The password provided is too weak.'));
          } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
            emit(RegisterAccountFailure(
                'The account already exists for that email.'));
          } else {
            emit(RegisterAccountFailure(e.toString()));
          }
        }

        try {
          CollectionReference users =
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User');
          print("Trying to add");
          await users.add({
            'username': event.username,
            'email': event.email,
            'password': event.password
          });
          print("User Created");
          emit(RegisterAccountSuccess());
        } catch (error) {
          emit(RegisterAccountFailure(error.toString()));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

I tried to debug for hours but no signs of any change at this point. It was working before firebase started showing this message in the authentication tab.
==> Cross origin redirect sign-in is no longer supported in many browsers. Update your app to ensure your users can continue to sign into your app.

there is nothing wrong with your code, this is a firebase auth issue, I was facing the same, all did was update firebase_auth and firebase_core to the latest version, and re-run the app, that solved the issue in my case.
See here for more details:

I thought stackoverflow is dead after AI, but AI failed to answer this question. AI won't beat ever human!

I had the same problem as you, what has helped me is not running the pub upgrade command on the console. I go to the flutter packages official (pub.dev), searched the auth and its related packages and installed them by adding their latest version under dependencies in pub.yaml file.
firebase_auth: ^5.3.3
firebase_core: ^3.8.0
firebase_storage: ^12.3.6
cloud_firestore: ^5.5.0
I hope, this would help at you end.

This answer may be late, but after some recent research, I've discovered that the bug has been fixed with the latest versions. This answer is being left to the people who are dealing with older versions and are unable to upgrade due to dependency constraints. This could be a temporary fix.
try {
    credentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (ex) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    showFlutterToast(context,
        message: ex.message.toString(), errorInfo: 'error');
    return false;
  } catch (e) {
    print("Creds: $credentials, Error: $e");
  }
  String uid;
  UserModel? userModel;
  if (credentials != null) {
    uid = credentials.user!.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot userData =
        await 

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
        userModel = UserModel.fromMap(userData.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      } else {
        User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        userModel = await FirebaseHelper.getUserModelById(currentUser!.uid);
      }

Here's how the pubspec.yaml looks:
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.31.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.0
  mobile_scanner: ^5.2.3

Explanation:
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword

has the bug but still manages to store the Firebase token that can be retrieved by
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser

So by Catching the exception and managing credentials based on the returned value you can have your userID.
P.S. This is not a real application code just recreated the bug for a quick fix for a friend's legacy app.
Feel free to contribute more to this answer!

The issue arises from mismatched or outdated Firebase dependencies. To resolve it, update all dependencies, including Firebase packages, to their latest major versions by running:
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Additionally, you might encounter an error related to the minimum SDK version required for Firebase Auth. To fix this, update your minSdkVersion to 23 in your android/app/build.gradle file as shown below:
android {
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
 }
}


Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more
